# Accessing webcam in my webpage, video not showing even if the browser has the access in the cam

Tags: javascript

I am trying to capture photo using my webcam in my website but the problem is the video is not showing in the webpage, even if the browser already has access of the webcam here the java script

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">
(function(){
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
                vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

                navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                navigator.getMedia({
                    video: true,
                    audio: false    
                }, function(stream){
                        video.scr = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
                        video.play();
                }, function(error){

                });
})();
```

then this is where I want to show the cam and capture images

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-2">
<!--Webcam-->
     <!--<img  border-radius: 50%; src="image" alt="Student Image">-->
     <video id="video" width="200" height="200"></video>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    Select Picture File to Upload:  <input type="file" name="image">
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Typo. Should be

```
video.src = ...
```

not

```
video.scr = ...
```